# When I update the data of the QTreeView, I have to recreate the medel and set it every time

Tags: pyqt5

I created a TreeView to switch the display of the treeview through two buttons,
But when I update the data in the treeview,
If I only use `self.model.layoutChanged.emit()` to trigger the update, it won’t work.
I have to create a new model and set it to take effect.
Is there a better way to solve it?(Sorry there is a lot of code in this demo.)

[image]

### Main Widget:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    sig_key = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.items = []
        self.tree_datas = {'A': ['a1', 'a2'], 'B': ['b1', 'b2']}
        self.model = TreeViewModel(self.items)
        self.treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.model)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('A')
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('B')
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.slot_select_tree)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.slot_select_tree)
        self.lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.treeview)

    def slot_select_tree(self):
        self.items.clear()
        root = self.sender().text()
        data = self.tree_datas.get(root)
        self.items.append(CustomNode(root))
        for i in data:
            self.items[-1].addChild(CustomNode(i))

        #!!!reset medel every time:
        self.model = TreeViewModel(self.items)
        self.treeview.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeview.expandAll()

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
```

### TreeViewModel:

```
class TreeViewModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
        def __init__(self, nodes):
            QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)
            self._root = CustomNode(None)
    
            for node in nodes:
                self._root.addChild(node)
    
        def rowCount(self, index):
            if index.isValid():
                return index.internalPointer().childCount()
            return self._root.childCount()
    
        def index(self, row, column, _parent=None):
            if not _parent or not _parent.isValid():
                parent = self._root
            else:
                parent = _parent.internalPointer()
    
            if not QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.hasIndex(self, row, column, _parent):
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    
            child = parent.child(row)
            if child:
                return QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, row, column, child)
            else:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    
        def parent(self, index):
            if index.isValid():
                p = index.internalPointer().parent()
                if p:
                    return QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(self, p.row(), 0, p)
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    
        def columnCount(self, index):
            if index.isValid():
                return index.internalPointer().columnCount()
            return self._root.columnCount()
    
        def data(self, index, role):
            if not index.isValid():
                return None
            node = index.internalPointer()
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return node.data(index.column())
            return None
```

### Tree Node

```
class CustomNode(object):
        def __init__(self, data):
            self._data = data
            if type(data) == tuple:
                self._data = list(data)
            if type(data) is str or not hasattr(data, '__getitem__'):
                self._data = [data]
    
            self._columncount = len(self._data)
            self._children = []
            self._parent = None
            self._row = 0
    
        def data(self, column):
            if column >= 0 and column < len(self._data):
                return self._data[column]
    
        def columnCount(self):
            return self._columncount
    
        def childCount(self):
            return len(self._children)
    
        def child(self, row):
            if row >= 0 and row < self.childCount():
                return self._children[row]
    
        def parent(self):
            return self._parent
    
        def row(self):
            return self._row
    
        def addChild(self, child):
            child._parent = self
            child._row = len(self._children)
            self._children.append(child)
            self._columncount = max(child.columnCount(), self._columncount)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Since you're always creating a new tree, there would be not a lot of difference between creating a new model or resetting it. In any case, you should use `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel`. `layoutChanged` is pointless for this, as it only used when the layout (not the "size") of the model is changed, for instance when doing sorting.

Comment: I added `self.model.beginResetModel()` and `self.model.endResetModel()` to the first and last lines of the `slot_select_tree` method, but they didn’t work.

Comment: You should also remove the existing children of the root node and replace them with the new ones. Note that all those operations should be done *in* the model class, not outside of it (while technically it doesn't change that much, it's conceptually better and easier to maintain). Besides that, as already said, since the model is being completely reset, there's practically no real difference between doing this or replacing with a new model.

Comment: @musicamante Oh, I See the problem.. I removed the existing children and added node again in the model. It’s worked. I'm very grateful to you.

Comment: @musicamante You helped me a lot of times,Do you have any donation link? I want to tip you a coffee.

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a PyQt-related website on my own. Check my profile the next time you get another useful answer or comment from mine ;-)

Comment: I am looking forward to it.

Comment: My website isn't up yet (I'm still working on it in my spare time), but I finally updated my profile and I've added a donation link if you still want to buy me that coffee ;-)